# Handling Navigation controllers with multiple storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I have a `navigationController` in my first storyboard. From that storyboard, I push a new `viewController` onto the stack but its in a different storyboard. When I try to change the background image for my second`viewController` only, it doesn't work.

In my first `viewController`, I programmatically segue to `UsersViewController`, which is my second VC. Here is my first view controller and storyboard:

```
 import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var welcomeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var splitLabel: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var rouletteLabel: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var quickLabel: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonStackView: UIStackView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()

    }

    func setup() {

        welcomeLabel.font = UIFont(name: Theme.headingFontName, size: 32)

        splitLabel.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Theme.mainFontName, size: 26)
        splitLabel.backgroundColor = Theme.accent
        splitLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        rouletteLabel.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Theme.mainFontName, size: 26)
        rouletteLabel.backgroundColor = Theme.delete
        rouletteLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        quickLabel.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Theme.mainFontName, size: 26)
        quickLabel.backgroundColor = Theme.edit
        quickLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }

    @IBAction func splitNavigation(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: String(describing: UsersViewController.self), bundle: nil)
        let vc  = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

}
```

[image]

In my `UsersViewController`, I try to change the background image of the `navigationbar`:

```
import UIKit

class UsersViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextBtn: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.reloadData()
        setup()

    }

    func setup() {
        view.backgroundColor = Theme.background

        nameTextField.borderStyle = .none
        nameTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
        nameTextField.underlined()

        viewContainer.backgroundColor = .white
        viewContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 40

    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationItem.title = "People"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "navBar"), for: .default)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toAddUserVC" {
            let popup = segue.destination as! AddUsersViewController
            popup.doneSaving = { [weak self] in
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

}

extension UsersViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Data.userModels.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! UsersTableViewCell
        let model = Data.userModels[indexPath.row]
        cell.setup(userModel: model)
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }

}
extension UITextField {
    func underlined(){
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(1.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = width
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

[image]
I don't know why, but every time I navigate to the `UsersViewController`, the background image flashes for a quick second, and then disappears. The title and bar buttons still show. Then, if I navigate back to the first `viewController`, the `NavigationBar` is gone. Here is a gif of what happens when I try to run the code if that helps.

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/fUwTMVbgHfFq89saHO)

I'm able to change the color, the translucence, and every other property of the `navigationbar`, expect this. I figure it something to do with the fact that it's in a different storyboard. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: In the second storyboard, what is the class of the initial view controller?

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying. It's SecondViewController, which is a ViewController.

Comment: If there's no one answering for a couple of hours, do you mind if you make a sample project and share it with us?

Comment: I think you need to share more details/code as the above code seems completely fine.

Comment: Okay I’ll update my question to provide more context

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue based on what you've said. In my tests, what happens is exactly what you'd expect: when we push to the SecondViewController, the nav bar image changes, and then when we go pop back to the first view controller, the nav bar image stays because we did nothing to change it back. Therefore I conclude that the problem lies in code you are not showing us.

Comment: "Oh I see what you are saying. It's SecondViewController, which is a ViewController" OK, but that's wrong. It needs to be UsersViewController. Otherwise you are accidentally running the code from some other view controller (SecondViewController) that you have not even shown us.

Comment: Yeah when I first posted the question, I referred to `UsersViewController` as `SecondViewController` just for simplicity. Then when I updated it to add more detail, I used `UsersViewController`. Ill double check the code I haven't posted but it didn't seem like it was relevant to the issue. Oh well, it definitely is affecting the output.